# How to use WITH clause and select clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

[click here to view screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKcWT.png)

Question: write a query to display the customer number, firstname, lastname for those client where total loan amount taken is maximum and at least taken from 2 bank branch.

I have tried the following query but I'm getting this error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Column 'customer.fname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Code:

```
with l as
(  
    select custid, sum(loan_amount) as tot 
    from loan
    group by custid 
    having count(bid) >= 2   
) 
select 
    concat(c.fname, c.ltname) as name,
    max(l.tot)
from 
    customer as c, l
where 
    l.custid = c.custid
```

Comment: just add `group by concat(c.fname,c.ltname)` at the end of your query

Comment: i already tried adding group by.But then it will give  multiple column but according to question  customer having max loan amount should be the output @vkp

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `GROUP BY` to select both aggregated and non-aggregated data,  so you need to decide how you want the data grouped.  You could do either

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.fname,c.ltname) as name, MAX(l.tot)
FROM customer AS c
INNER JOIN l ON l.custid=c.custid
GROUP BY c.fname,c.ltname
```

or

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.fname,c.ltname) as name, MAX(l.tot)
FROM customer AS c
INNER JOIN l ON l.custid=c.custid
GROUP BY concat(c.fname,c.ltname)
```

Please note the following:

- I converted the "old" join syntax to the more acceptable `INNER JOIN` syntax
- You *probably* want a space between the first and late name if you're displaying the results.

Comment: i already tried adding group by.But then it will give  multiple column but according to question  customer having max loan amount should be the output @D Stanley